# Providing In-App Purchase, in a free app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to submit a free app with In-App purchase in the Appstore which can be available in all geographies and not restricting to any particular geography.

However,I do not have financial account for all geographies,say, i just have a account in US .So, as i am making the app freely available for all geographies but do not have financial accounts for all geographies,how can a user outside US buy any enhancement through In-App purchase? Does Apple restrict such transactions any way? Or, does Apple reject such applications?

Supposedly,If this app  gets approved by apple and goes to app store and any user outside US downloads this app and tries to buy any enhancement using In-App purchase, how will the financial transaction happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be way off here but doesnt apple handle all the payment transactions themselves? I thought they processed everything, took their 30% cut then gave the developers their share. If that is case, they probably handle the international transactions and give you your share the same way they would any local transaction. It wouldnt make sense for you to have to have accounts all over the world in order to sell an international app.

Also, I dont believe this would have any effect on weather the app is approved or not. Apple wants as many people doing in-app purchases as possible so they can make as much money as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andre. I haven't handled a standard license yet, have always dealt in an enterprise one. I read somewhere in a forum that you are allowed to sell your app to only those geographies where you have valid bank accounts. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Vin I am 100% sure that you can have one bank account known to Apple, and they handle all transations, including international, and pay into it. You don't need to hold the account in the country you're selling in.

Comment: Yes, you need only one bank account. Preferably the one from your home country. It's quite hard to get a bank account in all regions of the world. There are a lot of countries that only allow you to have a bank account if you have a residence in this country. Apple will handle everything for you (that's why they get 30%). They transfer your proceeds to the account you specified in itunes connect.

Comment: Thanks fluchtpunk and badgerr for your comments, +1 to each one of you for clearing out my doubts.